# Vertical Rhythm not working when Headings go onto multiple lines

Tags: css

Is there a way to setup a CSS baseline grid (vertical rhythm) that doesn't fall apart if a heading ends up going on multiple lines?

Comment: What does "fall apart" mean?

Comment: Aside from that, what the heck is 'vertical rhythm'?

Comment: Vertical rhythm is a common term used in print/web design that is related to lining things up with an invisible vertical grid of margins (in this case leadings/line-heights). It can be done with text, images, and other graphical elements like horizontal rules.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have a method. It takes some CSS + Markup + Utility font.

Here is a codepen of a working solution with multiple blocks, font-sizes and fonts: 
https://codepen.io/shalanah/pen/RyEOEO

You can add as many characters as you'd like to the example posted and below and it will work.

Example Markup

```
<h1><span>Heading One</span></h1>
<p><span>Paragraph</span></p>
```

Example CSS

```
:root {
  --grid: 20; /* Vertical rhythm */
}

/* 1. Include a baselined font - This font is exactly 1em tall with no metrics below the baseline */
@font-face {
  font-family: "Baseline Em";
  src: url("https://rawgit.com/shalanah/baseline/98e925b/BaselineEm/baselineem-webfont.woff2") format("woff2"),
  url("https://rawgit.com/shalanah/baseline/98e925b/BaselineEm/baselineem-webfont.woff") format("woff"),
  url("https://rawgit.com/shalanah/baseline/98e925b/BaselineEm/baselineem-webfont.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

/* 2. Setting block elements up */
h1, p {
  font-family: "Baseline Em"; /* Baselined font only needed at block level */
  line-height: 1em;
}

/* 3. Ignore inline line-heights */
h1 *, p * {
  line-height: 0;
}

/* 4. Leadings and margins */
h1 {
  font-size: calc(var(--grid) * 4px); /* mult of grid - our leading */
  margin-bottom: calc(var(--grid) * 3px);
  margin-top: calc(var(--grid) * 3px);
}
p {
  font-size: calc(var(--grid) * 2px); /* mult of grid - our leading */
  margin-bottom: calc(var(--grid) * 1px);
}

/* 5. Inline styles, lots of freedom, don't need to be multiples of grid */
h1 > span {
  font-size: 100px;
  font-family: Arial; /* Any font you want */
}
p > span {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: Arial; /* Any font you want */
}
```

Most of the time leading isn't worth the time it takes to implement. I came up with this solution because I absolutely needed it. I wish that we had a leading property in CSS that we could use instead of line-height since line-height is a web-only invention.